# Configuring iOS Build settings

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, architecture, build-settings

I plan on releasing an update for my iPad app, even though some of the third party libraries have not been updated.

```
Architectures = standard(armv7, armv7s, arm64)
Valid Archs   = armv7
```

If I add armv7s or armv64 to Valid Archs the project won't build.

Will I be leaving out devices if I push this update to the app store?  It runs just fine on my iPad air with the A7 64 bit processor (and I believe armv7s is for the A6 chip, correct?).

Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

armv7s is a small extension of armv7, whereas arm64 is a completely different 64-bit architecture. You should not experience any build errors when building for armv7s, though many apps will have type issues when compiled against arm64 (defined types like NSInteger and CGFloat change size) -- and this is even more of a problem when dealing with third-party code. However, since the armv7s and arm64 chips are backwards compatible with armv7, and the benefits of the newer architectures are small for most apps, it's probably safer to build only for armv7. No devices since Apple switched to armv7 will be left out.